# how to achieve a few blocks in Show List. Sonata Admin

Tags: sonata-admin

how to achieve a few blocks in Show List in Sonata Admin Bundle?

[image: a few blocks in Show List]

I do not mean Tabs. Can it be done without custom template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know yet how to do this vertically, but horizontally:

```
$formMapper
  ->with('group1')
    ->add('foo')
  ->end()
  ->with('group2')
    ->add('bar')
    ->add('baz')
  ->end()
```